# install Virtualbox 6 in Linux Mint 19 Tara 32bit

Tags: virtualbox, installation, linux-mint

How can I install Virtualbox 6 in Liniux Mint 19 Tara 32 bits?

Kernel: 4.15.0-48-generic i686
           bits: 32 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: MATE 1.20.1 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu3)
           Distro: Linux Mint 19 Tara

Machine:   Device: laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: N/A v: F.20 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 308A v: KBC Version 26.08 serial: N/A
           BIOS: Hewlett-Packard v: 68PVU Ver. F.20 date: 12/01/2011

CPU:       Single core Intel Celeron 570 (-UP-) 
           arch: Conroe rev.1 cache: 1024 KB
           flags: (lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 ssse3) bmips: 4521 speed: 2260 MHz (max)

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot install VirtualBox 6 on i686** because [VirtualBox 6.0 discontinued 32-bit host support](https://web.archive.org/web/20190513224136/https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads):

> Please also use version 5.2 if you still need support for 32-bit hosts, as this has been discontinued in 6.0. Version 5.2 will remain supported until July 2020.

VirtualBox 5.2 is the last major version to support 32-bit hosts.

You can find VirtualBox 5.2 downloads here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_2